# How to fix this haskell function using take and drop while?

Tags: haskell

I am asked to create a haskell function that will perform the following:

```
group [1,1,2,3,3] = [[1,1],[2],[3,3]]

group [] = []
```

Essentially it groups the consecutive terms that are the same

I should use take and drop while:

```
group [] = []
group (x:xs) = (takeWhile cond xs ++ [x]) : group (dropWhile cond xs)
   where
    cond = (\x -> x == head xs)
```

Here is what I have.

The above works for cases where a single element is at the end: `group [1,1,2] == [[1,1],2]` but not for cases where it's in the middle: `group [1,1,1,2,4] == [[1,1,1],[4,2]]` (it should be `[[1,1,1],[4],[2]]`

What is my mistake in the function?

Comment: Two different variables are named `x`.

Comment: `group [1,1,2] == [[1,1],2]` I know that can't be true without even looking at the source of `group`, because the RHS is ill-typed.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: Your mistake is the usage of `head` in your condition. You want to compare with `x`, not `head xs`.

Stylistically, note also that

1. `something ++ [x]` is less practical (and "efficient", although it doesn't really matter here) as `x : something` here, as order doesn't matter,
2. a function as `f = \x -> something` should really be written as `f x = something`,
3. and you probably shouldn't use the same variable name to refer to different values, it's get confusing very easily.

Your function cond is easily rewritten using a partially applied `==`:

```
group [] = []
group (x:xs) = (x : takeWhile cond xs) : group (dropWhile cond xs)
  where cond = (==) x
```

This yields the expected result for `group [1,1,1,2,4]`.

Comment: Did you mean to say "_less_ practical" instead of "_more_ practical"?